# Making react-native-autocomplete-input visible when keyboard is opened

Tags: react-native

I use [react-native-autocomplete-input](https://github.com/l-urence/react-native-autocomplete-input) component, which is **on the bottom of screen**, but I don't know how to make result list visible when keyboard is opened. I tried to use `ScrollView` and [react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) component, but result list is behind the keyboard.

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Platform,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import KeyboardSpacer from 'react-native-keyboard-spacer';
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';

const API = 'https://swapi.co/api';

class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      query: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${API}/films/`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const { results: films } = json;
        this.setState({ films });
      });
  }

  findFilm(query) {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }

    const { films } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    return films.filter(film => film.title.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const films = this.findFilm(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Autocomplete
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
            data={films.length === 1 && comp(query, films[0].title) ? [] : films}
            defaultValue={query}
            onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
            placeholder="Enter Star Wars film title"
            renderItem={({ title, release_date }) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: title })}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                  {title} ({release_date.split('-')[0]})
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
          />
        </ScrollView>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' ? <KeyboardSpacer /> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;

export default styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'proxima_nova_regular',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  scrollView: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flex: 1,
  },
  autocompleteContainer: {
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginTop: 400,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    margin: 2,
  },
});
```

Comment: Remove marginTop from  autocompleteContainer style class.

Comment: I need autocomplete component on the bottom

Comment: Then add marginBottom on focus of autocomplete textfield.

Comment: It doesn't help, you just make a gap between result list and textinput

Comment: If your autocomplete is of fixed height or there is a max height, you can `addListener` on the keyboard and dynamically place the input with the padding/margin of the autocomplete.

Comment: @AlexBarton I am sorry, but I don't understand. If I put padding/margin for the input in autocomplete component, I have a gap between result list and input. How this can solve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering your case, you would need [`react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

Although React Native has done a good job in implementing [`KeyboardAvoidingView`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html), but it has many issues as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20keyboardavoidingview%20in%3Atitle%20), particularly in a `ScrollView`, where *it makes an extra slack on the bottom*

And since the list items content can be dynamic, therefore it is necessary to wrap them inside a `ScrollView`.

Here are the changes that you can do in your code.

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'

<KeyboardAwareScrollView
    innerRef={ref => this.scrollView = ref} //... Access the ref for any other functions here
    contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
    <Autocomplete
        onFocus={() => {this.scrollView.props.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}} // ... Scroll To End on TextInput focus
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
        data={films.length === 1 && comp(query, films[0].title) ? [] : films}
        defaultValue={query}
        onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
        placeholder="Enter Star Wars film title"
        renderItem={({ title, release_date }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: title })}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                    {title} ({release_date.split('-')[0]})
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
    />    
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works very well. I will award your answer tomorrow. The system doesn't allow me to do it sooner.